# Randomly select a number multiple cells within a range based a cell value

Tags: excel, vba, select, random

I would like to select a number of cells within a range (C7:M37), but some of the cells in that range are empty and should not be picked. In addition, the number is base on an equation (R41) so the number of select cells would be different each time. Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) would seem to be a solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the insight, I guess my wording is poor, I would like to randomly select a number of cells based on a cell value.

Comment: @YSCheung "Is that possible?" <-- I think yes.. mind sharing the sample data to proceed... depending on how many of the cell is empty, the suggested formula may change.

Answer (score 0):

If you just use all cells it'll be :

```
=INDEX(C7:M37,RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS(C7:M37)),RANDBETWEEN(1,COLUMNS(C7:M37)))
```

but if you want to ignore the empty cell .. need more info to be firm.. else it'll be a just a simple nested if="" .